# Why is fluoride the most nucleophilic halide in aprotic solvents?

Tags: halides, solvents, nucleophilicity

I am confused on the topic of electronegative nucleophiles, and polar aprotic solvents.

From my understanding, the more electronegative a nucleophile is, the weaker of a nucleophile it will be, because atoms will be less likely to share its electron density.

However, in a polar aprotic solvent, because H-bonding cannot occur, it seems as if the trend of nucleophilicity is such that $\ce{F- > Cl- > Br- > I-}$.

**Can someone please clarify how this is possible?** I would have expected $\ce{F-}$ to be the LEAST nucleophilic nucleophile in a polar aprotic solvent, because it is the most electronegative atom. Therefore according to the first point I learned, I thought it should be the weakest nucleophile.

All this is what I've learned through reading Kaplan's Organic Chemistry Review.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/47072/nucleophilicity-with-respect-to-the-solvent https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/95710/order-of-halide-nucleophilicity-in-dmf

Answer (score 3):

When talking about elements of a group, the size of the atom is more effective than the electronegativity factor.
As $\ce{F-}$ size is too short so its electron density will be much higher than other hallogens.

In aprotic solvent the order of nucleophillicity:
$\ce{F- > Cl- > Br- >I-}$(No hydration occurs) In protic solvant(like $\ce{H2O}$) its reversed because of hydration of ions having much electron density.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE!  Please note that formulas can be better expressed with \$\ce{ }\$ for chemical formulas/equations, \$ \$ for math term/equations, and \$\pu{ }\$ for units. More information is available in [this meta post](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/86/23561) Also, take a minute to look over the [help center](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help) and [tour page](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) to better understand our guidelines and question policies if you haven't already.