# Which is a stronger nucleophile in aprotic solvent: water or hydrogen sulfide?

Tags: nucleophilicity

Which one is the stronger nucleophile in aprotic solvent: $\ce{H2O}$ or $\ce{H2S}?$

According to my notes, nucleophilicity order is directly proportional to basicity order in an aprotic medium, and is inversely proportional to basicity order in protic medium.

And $\ce{H2O}$ is a stronger base than $\ce{H2S},$ so it should be the strong nucleophile, but the answer is given as $\ce{H2S}$ is the stronger nucleophile. What is the reason for that? Am I missing something?

Comment: Related: [Nucleophilicity with respect to the solvent](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/47072/81509)

Comment: H2S is a stronger base then H2O, not that it matters much. More importantly trialkylthionium ions are *much* more stable then oxonium analogues.